# NSOutlineView Source List Section Headers

Tags: cocoa, delegates, datasource, nsoutlineview

I'm using a view-based NSOutlineView to create a source list.
The NSOutlineView is connected to a Data Source and Delegate object.

However, I can't seem to find what I need to implement in order to utilize the section headers (e.g., "LIBRARY", "STORE", "DEVICES", etc. in iTunes). What methods do I need to implement in the Data Source/Delegate to achieve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

IIRC you just need to implement `NSOutlineViewDelegate`'s `outlineView:isGroupItem:`.